# How to set values to a formControl from an array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've an array of objects, and I'm trying, to iterate through that array and

1. set the values to a formControl dynamically
2. do not display if the value is null.

couldn't find any similar solutions, any references or examples would be appreciated.

.html

```
<form [formGroup]="testForm">
  <div class="class" *ngFor="let item of items">
    <span>{{ item.name }}</span>
    <span>{{ item.email }}</span>
    <div>
      <input type="text" formControlName="number">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

.ts

```
testForm: FormGroup;

  items: any[] = [
    {
      name: 'Rob',
      email: 'Rob@test.com',
      number: 1234
    },
    {
      name: 'Mack',
      email: 'Mack@test.com',
      number: 9876
    },
    {
      name: 'Mack',
      email: 'Mack@test.com',
      number: null
    }
  ];
  get number() {
    return this.testForm.get('number');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.testForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      number: [this.items[0].number, [Validators.required]]
    });
  }
```

Comment: Have I solved the issue? Do you have any question about my solution?

Comment: Thanks much, I'm just going through the solution and will update the post for any questions. @DamienAsseya

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the data to display as desired. It's a complicated process. You are on the right track. But you can't achieve the expected result without using a `formArray`.

Stackblitz Link - [click here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formarray-display-data?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

.html

```
<form [formGroup]="testform">
  <div *ngFor="let item of itemArray;let i = index" formArrayName="items" >
    <div [formGroupName]="i">
          <span>{{ item.controls.name.value }}</span>
          <span>{{ item.email}}</span>
          <div>
            <input type="text" formControlName="number">
          </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
</form>
```

.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormArray, Validators } from "@angular/forms";
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public testform: FormGroup;
    public data: any[] = [
    {
      name: 'Rob',
      email: 'Rob@test.com',
      number: 1234
    },
    {
      name: 'Mack',
      email: 'Mack@test.com',
      number: 9876
    },
    {
      name: 'Mack',
      email: 'Mack@test.com',
      number: null
    }
  ];
  public itemGroup: FormArray;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    const arryOfItemGroup = this.data.map(item => {
      return this.createItemGroup(
        item.name,
        item.email,
        item.number
      );
    });
    this.testform = this.fb.group({
      items: this.fb.array(arryOfItemGroup)
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  get itemArray() {
    return this.testform.get("items")["controls"] as FormArray;
  }

  private createItemGroup(name, email, number) {
    return this.fb.group({
      name: [name],
      email: [email],
      number: [number]
    });
  }

}
```